# Can anyone please help me in achieving one of the moderate complex scenario using sed or awk commands?

Tags: shell-script

Below is the scenario

I have one list file where I have list file  with table names lets say 10 tables and I have another file with all the create DDLs about 100.

I need to extract create DDLS from the second file for the tables that exist in the first file. I have achieved this using `sed` command. However, I ran in to issue where my command is copying twice for few tables and as well as some extra ones which are not in the first file

For Ex;

my `List_File.txt` has

```
ACASE
ABC
ABCH
```

`CREATE_DDLS.txt` has

```
CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.ACASE
(
    COLUMN1,
    COLUMN2,
    COLUMN3
) ;

CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.ACASE01
(
    COLUMN1,
    COLUMN2,
    COLUMN3
) ;

CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.ACASE03
(
    COLUMN1,
    COLUMN2,
    COLUMN3
);

CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.ABC
(
    COLUMN1,
    COLUMN2,
    COLUMN3
) ;

CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.ABCD
(
    COLUMN1,
    COLUMN2,
    COLUMN3
) ;
```

Scenario 1:

ACASE exist in the list file and there are ACASE/ACASE01/ACASE03 in the second file, below command is copying all three tables where I need only ACASE create DDL to the output.

Scenario 2:

ABC & ABCD exist in list file, command is outputting ABCD table twice where I need only one ABCD.

Below is the command I am executing

```
while read -r line
 do
  sed -n '/CREATE TABLE SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME/,/\;/p' Create DDLS file
done < List file > NewFile.txt
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: We cannot help you parse data if you don't show us the data. So, please [edit] your question and add i) an example input file and ii) the output you want to see from that example. Note that your shell loop doesn't make much sense: you arte reading `line` but never use it and instead are running `sed` on three files, one called `Create`, one called `DDLS` and one called `file`.

Comment: Is this two questions in one?

Comment: One question but two scenarios Jeremy.

Answer (score 1):

Your example and/or attempt is wrong.

Anyhow, if I take your example file, your script probably could be

```
while read -r line;  do
  sed -n "/CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.$line/,/;/p" CREATE_DDLs.txt ;
done < List_File.txt
```

and it will match all records, because `ACASE` will also match `ACASE01`. Use `$` as an anchor for line ending:

```
while read -r line;  do
  sed -n "/CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.$line$/,/;/p" CREATE_DDLs.txt ;
done < List_File.txt
```

That said, for a longer list of tables, it's not very efficient to scan the whole file over and over, while with extended regular expressions you can search for something like `(ACASE|ABC|ABCH)`, so put that first file in the right form and use it in the search pattern:

```
TABLES=$(cat List_File.txt|tr '\n' '|')
sed -nE "/CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.(${TABLES%|})$/,/;/p" CREATE_DDLs.txt
```

The `tr` will replace all newlines with OR bars while the `%|` in the variable expansion will remove the trailing bar.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using *paragraph mode" in GNU awk:

```
gawk '
    NR==FNR{tbl["CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>." $1]; next} ($1 in tbl){ORS=RT; print}
  ' List_File.txt RS= FS='\n' CREATE_DDLS.txt
CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.ACASE
(
    COLUMN1,
    COLUMN2,
    COLUMN3
) ;

CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.ABC
(
    COLUMN1,
    COLUMN2,
    COLUMN3
) ;
```

You can do essentially the same in any awk, except you won't have access to `RT` so will need to set `ORS` to something fixed like `\n\n`